# Are laravel relationships enough to construct a good database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am starting a project which requires some kind of hard (complex) database structure (meaning that It's not easy to draw a database structure).

My questions:

1. I know very well how laravel relationships work. Will those relationships be enough to construct a database by following it and then the database must be constructed so good that code written in application should be super flexible.
2. If those relationships are not enough, what do you advise me to do?

Comment: Do you have an example of something you feel won't work?

Comment: Yes the laravel relationships are good enough to do anything that you want.

Comment: Don't know. Just want to make sure :) As I know laravel relationships, but I might not be the good db administrator, but it's me who has to design it . that's why

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent Relationships are good for almost all cases, otherwise if you need a more complex query you can use Fluent Queries

[Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)